# Pronunciation of an acronym as a word - C as a stop or a fricative

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

At my place of work in the US at an agency, there is an acronym that is fairly well known: FOCI
I've noticed some pronounce it "FOSI" (with a sibilant(?) C) and some "FOKI" (with a hard C) with a long O and a long I. (I don't know the proper way to describe these things, sorry)

If it matters, the acronym will expand as: Foreign Ownership, Control or Influence.

Which pronunciation would be more accurate, or better, if either? How would this be determined?

Answer (score 2):

Unless there's someone who "owns" an acronym (e.g. they coined it, or they are responsible for the documents that authoritatively define it, etc) the "correct" pronunciation is largely determined by how people pronounce it in practice - there are no general rules for this.

On this specific example, note that there is a word "foci" (plural of "focus"), which is [most commonly pronounced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foci) with a soft C ("foe-sigh"), but sometimes with a hard C ("foe-kie") - this seems to match your experience of how people pronounce the acronym, so it's likely at least some people take their cue from how they pronounce the word.

Comment: I don't know if the soft C pronunciation of "foci" is an American thing but I've never heard it and British dictionaries don't list it at all ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/foci))

Comment: @ChrisH: Definitely not just an American thing (I'm from the UK). Some dictionaries list soft-C as the [only pronunciation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/focus). That Collins entry is odd, because their entry for "focus" lists the soft-C pronunciation of "foci" as the most common - I'd guess that the "hard-C only" thing is an error.

Comment: You can listen online to some of the variants. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xDqDgU_5h8

Comment: @DjinTonic: Thanks but I wouldn't recommend that video to someone wanting the "correct" pronunciation - I don't think the person speaking is a native speaker, and the first pronunciation they use is uncommon.

Comment: @psmears I looked at Cambridge first and they didn't list any pronunciation, but that might be their mobile view. I work in physics/optics so it's not an uncommon word in my field

Comment: Oxford doesn't give the plural's pronunciation; Cambridge gives only the sibilant one; Collins gives three variants with the sibilant listed first. When phonemically transcribed broadly into simple IPA (without attention to variable phonetic diphthongs that have no affect on which phoneme was used), the plural of the Latinate word /ˈfokəs/ is commonly pronounced /ˈfosaɪ/, but any of /ˈfokaɪ/, /ˈfosi/, and even /ˈfoki/ can also be heard from time to time, not to mention the ever-popular /ˈfokəsəz/. 

Comment: @tchrist: FWIW [Oxford Advanced Learner's](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/focus_2?q=foci) gives both soft/hard C with soft listed first.

Comment: Assuming for discussion there were a single  or even agreed-upon pronunciation of the English word "foci," that wouldn't necessarily dictate how employees would choose to pronounce the acronym FOCI. You can make a case for a hard K since the C stands for Control, rather than base it all on a "best" pronunciation of the lower-case word.

Comment: @Djin: Yes indeed, there are different pronunciations; that's why I was careful to say "most commonly pronounced", not "always" or "correct". Yes, there are other motivations for how people might choose to pronounce the word, which is why I said that it's *likely* that *some* people pronounce it that based on that reason. I have made no claims of exclusivity, merely pointed out a relevant factor :)

Comment: Chambers gives only fōsī (e.g. ['fousai]) and I have never heard anything else. It's not an Americanism. For "loci", Chambers likewise gives lōsī; it also gives lōki but that's because it gives lokoos (short oo) (i.e. ['lɒkʊs] as an alternative for the singular. It lists various Latin phrases such as locus classicus -- not an issue with "focus".

Answer (score 0):

If everyone where you are agreed to a pronunciation, that would be the "right" one. Since the word *foci* has a number of pronunciations, it's logical that opinions  differ on what to do with the acronym. My hunch is that there will be the tomato--tomahto proponents, unless you all get an email with the agency's "policy" regarding the pronunciation.